# Problem with unknown ports on Spring Eureka Client registration

Tags: spring-boot, heroku, https, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

Well, a have tried ALL tutorials, ALL answer on Stackoverflow. But I still face the same error:

On Heroku, Eureka Clients are receiving random ports that I don't know where they come from.

And these random ports are different from Heroku Environment variable $PORT. I know that $PORT is the container Dyno port, not the host port xxxxx.herokuapp.com that the out side world can access. Again, I don't know where these ports come from!!!

The link clients in the Eureka Dashboard stay like this:

hdfb2324-8jfw-83ud-dkdf-9ej90jefj201.qwer.dyno.rt.heroku.com:inight-ws-gateway:${RANDOM PORT}

When I click, go to https://inight-ws-gateway.herokuapp.com:${RANDOM PORT}/actuator/info. I take the Timeout because the correct port is 443, Https default.

I have 3 applications, 1 Eureka Server and 2 Eureka Clients (Zuul Gateway and a trivial Rest API).

Every works ok when I run in my localhost, but when I deploy in Heroku, it's happen.

**Eureka Server application.yaml:**

```
server:
  port: ${PORT} 

spring:
  application:
    name: '@project.artifactId@' # inight-ws-discovery
    version: '@project.version@'

eureka:
  client:
    fetch-registry: false
    register-with-eureka: false

management:
  endpoints:
    enabled-by-default: false
    web:
      exposure:
        include:
        - health
        - info
  endpoint:
    health:
      enabled: true
    info:
      enabled: true
```

**Eureka Client (Zuul gateway) application.yaml:**

```
server:
  port: ${PORT}

spring:
  application:
    name: '@project.artifactId@' # inight-ws-gateway
    version: '@project.version@'

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: ${INIGHT_EUREKA_INSTANCE_HOSTNAME} # inight-ws-gateway.herokuapp.com
  client:
    enabled: true
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: ${INIGHT_EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE_URL_DEFAULTZONE} # https://inight-ws-discovery.herokuapp.com/eureka/
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true

zuul:
  sensitive-headers:
  - Cookie

management:
  endpoints:
    enabled-by-default: false
    web:
      exposure:
        include:
        - health
        - info
        - routes
  endpoint:
    health:
      enabled: true
    info:
      enabled: true
    routes:
      enabled: true

jwt:
  config:
    privateKey: ${INIGHT_JWT_CONFIG_PRIVATEKEY}
```

**Eureka Client (Rest API) application.yaml:**

```
server:
  port: ${PORT}

spring:
  application:
    name: '@project.artifactId@' # inight-ws-auth
    version: '@project.version@'
  datasource:
    hikari:
      schema: inight
      jdbc-url: ${INIGHT_DATASOURCE_JDBC_URL}
      username: ${INIGHT_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
      password: ${INIGHT_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
      driver-class-name: ${INIGHT_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME}
  jpa:
    show-sql: ${INIGHT_JPA_SHOW_SQL}
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: ${INIGHT_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO}

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: ${INIGHT_EUREKA_INSTANCE_HOSTNAME} inight-ws-auth.herokuapp.com
  client:
    enabled: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: ${INIGHT_EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE_URL_DEFAULTZONE} https://inight-ws-discovery.herokuapp.com/eureka/
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true

management:
  endpoints:
    enabled-by-default: false
    web:
      exposure:
        include:
        - health
        - info
  endpoint:
    health:
      enabled: true
    info:
      enabled: true

jwt:
  config:
    privateKey: ${INIGHT_JWT_CONFIG_PRIVATEKEY}

swagger.basePackage: br.com.bz.inight.auth.controller
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my fault!!!!!
I have a couple of microservices on Heroku:

- Eureka Server
- Zuul Gateway
- Some app services

The link on Eureka Server Dashboard, **doesn't matter**. Whats matter is the https://GATEWAY.herokuapp.com/actuator/routes and the `<port enabled="true">80</port>` on https://EUREKA_SERVER.herokuapp.com/eureka/apps.

But for this happen (`<port enabled="true">80</port>` on app services) you **MUST ,EXPLICITLY**, declare in application.yaml

```
eureka:
  instance:
    non-secure-port: 80
    hostname: ${EUREKA_CLIENT_INSTANCE_HOSTNAME} # herokuapp_name.herokuapp.com
```

If you read the documentation, you will see that the property `eureka.instance.non-secure-port` has the default value 80. I don't know why, but, if you don't declare it, the `<port enabled="true">80</port>` are not set up on microservices applications on Eureka Server.

Check the tutorial https://blog.heroku.com/managing_your_microservices_on_heroku_with_netflix_s_eureka.

Well, these are my architecture application.yaml:

**coffee-eureka-server** application.yaml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: '@project.artifactId@'

server:
  port: ${PORT}

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: ${EUREKA_CLIENT_INSTANCE_HOSTNAME} # herokuapp_name.herokuapp.com
  client:
    fetch-registry: false
    register-with-eureka: false
    service-url:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_SERVER_URI}/eureka/ # in this case, same value of eureka.instance.hostname, but with https:// prefix, of course
```

**coffee-zuul-gateway** application.yaml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: '@project.artifactId@'

server:
  port: ${PORT}

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: ${EUREKA_CLIENT_INSTANCE_HOSTNAME} # herokuapp_name.herokuapp.com
  client:
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_SERVER_URI}/eureka/

management:
  endpoints:
    enabled-by-default: true
    web:
      exposure:
        include:
        - routes
        - info
        - health
```

**coffee-simple-ms** application.yaml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: '@project.artifactId@'

server:
  port: ${PORT}

eureka:
  instance:
    non-secure-port: 80 # <<<<<<<<< HERE
    hostname: ${EUREKA_CLIENT_INSTANCE_HOSTNAME} # herokuapp_name.herokuapp.com
  client:
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_SERVER_URI}/eureka/
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I click, go to `https://inight-ws-gateway.herokuapp.com:${RANDOM PORT}/actuator/info`. I take the Timeout because the correct port is
>   443, Https default.

When you are hosting on localhost the link would be: `http://localhost:${PORT}/actuator/info`

On Heroku this link is: `https://inight-ws-gateway.herokuapp.com/actuator/info`

The difference:

- It is using http **secure**, https
- The port number is "gone"

The hostname `inight-ws-gateway.herokuapp.com` is automatically translated into a `${IP_ADDRESS}:${PORT}`.

You will need to adjust your source code for the https URL generation.

---

Your web application will run on a port different from the usual http/https port. It does not have to be 80, 8080 or 443. It can be any port. And that port is specified by Heroku through `$PORT`.

Comment: hi! Tank you!! But why if we track this heroku tutorial https://blog.heroku.com/managing_your_microservices_on_heroku_with_netflix_s_eureka we don`t have this problem with clients ports?